# What would this design be called?

Tags: style-identification

[image]

This is my first post here. I have been trying to find a tutorial or other guidance how to draw something with this style. Does it have a name?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not every style has a name...

...although I'd lean towards calling this something like **1970s retro** possibly. 
There's not much to go on.

Comment: That sounds about right. My initial guess "acid jazz funk" somehow does *not* sound right...

Comment: thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Ball_Liao if this post answers your question, don't forget to mark it as accepted; it's the way we say "thank you" around here. Check [ask] and the [tour] to learn how the site works.